# Combining dictionaries from two lists of dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, mergeddictionaries

I have two lists that are full of dictionaries.

```py
l1 = l1 = [{'sku': '1122564', 'mfg': 'KANCA', 'mfgPartNumber': 'KC6247VMV2', 'import productNo': 'KANCA-KC6247VMV2', 'dept': 11, 'class': 30}, 
    {'sku': '1122565', 'mfg': 'KANCA', 'mfgPartNumber': 'KC6247VMV2', 'import productNo': 'KANCA-KC6247VMV2', 'dept': 11, 'class': 30}, 
    {'sku': '1122566', 'mfg': 'KANCA', 'mfgPartNumber': 'KC6247VMV2', 'import productNo': 'KANCA-KC6247VMV2', 'dept': 11, 'class': 30}, 
    {'sku': '1122567', 'mfg': 'KANCA', 'mfgPartNumber': 'KC6247VMV2', 'import productNo': 'KANCA-KC6247VMV2', 'dept': 11, 'class': 30}]
```

```py
l2 = [{'mfgPartNumber': 'KC6247VMV2', 'selected mgmt structure': 'A2021051106', 'mapped webStructure': '380'}]
```

for this particular case, l1 contains a total of 92 dictionaries and l2 contains 12 dictionaries, but I am showing you an example with less cases (for those who can't see how obvious that is).

I've tried this:

```
l3 = l1.update(l2)
```

and this:

```
def Merge(d1, d2)):
    result = d1 | d2
    return result

l3 = Merge(l1, l2)
```

But this didn't work. What I'm really looking for is this:

```
l3 = [{'sku': '1122564', 'mfg': 'KANCA', 'mfgPartNumber': 'KC6247VMV2', 'import productNo': 'KANCA-KC6247VMV2', 'dept': 11, 'class': 30, 'selected mgmt structure': 'A2021051106', 'mapped webStructure': '380'},
    {'sku': '1122565', 'mfg': 'KANCA', 'mfgPartNumber': 'KC6247VMV2', 'import productNo': 'KANCA-KC6247VMV2', 'dept': 11, 'class': 30, 'selected mgmt structure': 'A2021051106', 'mapped webStructure': '380'},
       {'sku': '1122566', 'mfg': 'KANCA', 'mfgPartNumber': 'KC6247VMV2', 'import productNo': 'KANCA-KC6247VMV2', 'dept': 11, 'class': 30, 'selected mgmt structure': 'A2021051106', 'mapped webStructure': '380'},
        {'sku': '1122567', 'mfg': 'KANCA', 'mfgPartNumber': 'KC6247VMV2', 'import productNo': 'KANCA-KC6247VMV2', 'dept': 11, 'class': 30, 'selected mgmt structure': 'A2021051106', 'mapped webStructure': '380'}]
```

Can anyone help out?

Much Appreciated.

Comment: Well, in **this** particular case `l1` contains 5 dictionaries and `l2` contains single. I can't find any code in your question, will be good to include your efforts.

Comment: You need to transform your `l2` into a single dictionary (`mapping = {d.pop("mfgPartNumber"): d for d in l2}`) and then create new list including all pairs from `mapping` into every dictionary (`[{**d, **mapping[d["mfgPartNumber"]]} for d in l1]`).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are looking for something like this:

```
l1 = [{'sku': '1122564', 'mfg': 'KANCA', 'mfgPartNumber': 'KC6247VMV2', 'import productNo': 'KANCA-KC6247VMV2', 'dept': 11, 'class': 30}, 
    {'sku': '1122565', 'mfg': 'KANCA', 'mfgPartNumber': 'KC6247VMV2', 'import productNo': 'KANCA-KC6247VMV2', 'dept': 11, 'class': 30}, 
    {'sku': '1122566', 'mfg': 'KANCA', 'mfgPartNumber': 'KC6247VMV2', 'import productNo': 'KANCA-KC6247VMV2', 'dept': 11, 'class': 30}, 
    {'sku': '1122567', 'mfg': 'KANCA', 'mfgPartNumber': 'KC6247VMV2', 'import productNo': 'KANCA-KC6247VMV2', 'dept': 11, 'class': 30}]
l2 = [{'mfgPartNumber': 'KC6247VMV2', 'selected mgmt structure': 'A2021051106', 'mapped webStructure': '380'}]

def merge(l1, l2):
    l2_merged = {}
    for d in l2:
        l2_merged.update(d)
    return [d | l2_merged for d in l1]

print(merge(l1, l2))
```

However, this depends on exactly how you want the dictionaries in l2 to be merged, which is not so clear from your question.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```py
l1 = [{'sku': '1122564', 'mfg': 'KANCA', 'mfgPartNumber': 'KC6247VMV2', 'import productNo': 'KANCA-KC6247VMV2', 'dept': 11, 'class': 30}, 
    {'sku': '1122565', 'mfg': 'KANCA', 'mfgPartNumber': 'KC6247VMV2', 'import productNo': 'KANCA-KC6247VMV2', 'dept': 11, 'class': 30}, 
    {'sku': '1122566', 'mfg': 'KANCA', 'mfgPartNumber': 'KC6247VMV2', 'import productNo': 'KANCA-KC6247VMV2', 'dept': 11, 'class': 30}, 
    {'sku': '1122567', 'mfg': 'KANCA', 'mfgPartNumber': 'KC6247VMV2', 'import productNo': 'KANCA-KC6247VMV2', 'dept': 11, 'class': 30}]

l2 = [{'mfgPartNumber': 'KC6247VMV2', 'selected mgmt structure': 'A2021051106', 'mapped webStructure': '380'}]

l3 = [dct | l2[0] for dct in l1]

[print(x) for x in l3]
```

Output:

```
{'sku': '1122564', 'mfg': 'KANCA', 'mfgPartNumber': 'KC6247VMV2', 'import productNo': 'KANCA-KC6247VMV2', 'dept': 11, 'class': 30, 'selected mgmt structure': 'A2021051106', 'mapped webStructure': '380'}
{'sku': '1122565', 'mfg': 'KANCA', 'mfgPartNumber': 'KC6247VMV2', 'import productNo': 'KANCA-KC6247VMV2', 'dept': 11, 'class': 30, 'selected mgmt structure': 'A2021051106', 'mapped webStructure': '380'}
{'sku': '1122566', 'mfg': 'KANCA', 'mfgPartNumber': 'KC6247VMV2', 'import productNo': 'KANCA-KC6247VMV2', 'dept': 11, 'class': 30, 'selected mgmt structure': 'A2021051106', 'mapped webStructure': '380'}
{'sku': '1122567', 'mfg': 'KANCA', 'mfgPartNumber': 'KC6247VMV2', 'import productNo': 'KANCA-KC6247VMV2', 'dept': 11, 'class': 30, 'selected mgmt structure': 'A2021051106', 'mapped webStructure': '380'}
```

Comment: @FlaskyPG Did this answer your question? Feel free to mark one of the answers "accepted". Do you need any more help?